# Subclassed UIButton title font size changing unexpectedly

Tags: swift, uibutton, subclass

I'm using protocol delegate to set the title of a UIButton. However, somewhere along the line the font size is unexpectedly changing from 14 to 17. I've tried subclassing the button to keep the font at size 14, but clearly something is going wrong. It's been suggested that perhaps there's a conflict somewhere with the font size. However, I can't find any code that creates conflict.

Subclassed button:

```
import UIKit

class typeButton: UIButton {
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 14)
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
       super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

Protocol extension:

```
extension ObservationDetailViewController: MushroomTypeDelegate {
    func didSelectMushroom(name: String) {
        typeButton.setTitle(name, for: .normal)
        observation?.type = name
    }
} // End of Extension
```

The button is classed via Storyboard. If I place a breakpoint on the line setting the button title `typeButton.setTitle(name, for: .normal)` [it shows the font at size 14](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjxDV.png) . Yet, as I move past the breakpoint the font is unexpectedly changed to a larger size. I was able to use attributed text, & setAttributedTitle to fix this, but I'm curious why the font size is being changed.

[Link to GitHub file](https://github.com/basedinbham/FungiFinder2.0/blob/fontIssue/FungiFinderFinal/Controllers/ViewControllers/Observations/ObservationDetailViewController.swift)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the font size in `init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` since you classed the button from storyboard:

```swift
class TypeButton: UIButton {
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
       super.init(coder: aDecoder)
       commonInit()
    }

    private func commonInit() {
        titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 14)
    }
}
```

And make sure the font name is correct.

Comment: The same issue still appears; printing out the font point size in console will show 14, but it's changed to 17 before being displayed. I'm assuming there must be some conflict within my code.